# I would like to remotely power on and off my Lenovo Yoga

Tags: laptop, keyboard, remote-desktop

I am using a Lenovo Yoga laptop as a Plex server, and sometimes it crashes. I want a way to power cycle it from any state while I am away. As far as I can tell the motherboard does not support wake on LAN or power state after loss of power.

I have a desktop computer that I can remotely turn on and off and control near my laptop. I also have a Logitech USB dongle keyboard with a power button that will turn on the laptop.

I am looking for any way to turn this laptop on. Some kind of remote controllable button presser or some kind of way to send the power-on keyboard stroke from my desktop computer to my laptop.

Comment: If your mainboard doesn't support these two states, I think you're out of luck. Also, questions asking that we recommend hardware or software are off topic on this site. If you're looking for a physical manipulator, look for smart home devices that can push physical buttons.

Comment: You can purchase commercial remote control power switches.   See if that will help you.

Comment: @John I think that would require the laptop to support the "power state after power loss" options that OP says theirs does not.

Comment: It might be. Both laptops and desktops use soft power buttons, so it would have to be connected in. It is an idea and the OP needs to determine if it would fit.

Comment: Get cat. Put laser on electric vibrator. Stick laser and vibrator above PC, point to ON button. Add remote (e.g., WiFi switch). Turn on motor and laser *via* WiFi, cat taps button. Viola! She plays.